# How to stop warning for unused variable in geany for C++ in ubuntu?

Tags: c++

**How to stop warning for unused variable in geany for C++ in ubuntu?**
warning:
c.cpp:11:6: warning: unused variable ‘k’ [-Wunused-variable]

Comment: This not an ubuntu question, but how compiler deals with unused variables. Please provide a minimum code that compiles.

Comment: Delete the unused variables!

Answer (score 2):

Either:

- Use the variable;
- Or remove it;
- Or mark it as unused (using the `[[maybe_unused]]` [attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), if you have it, or the GCC-specific `unused` [variable attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes)).

Comment: Yet another way would be casting it to void  – or does that fall under 'using it' already?

Comment: @Aconcagua The semantics of that could be argued about, but IMO it's in a way "using it". :)

Comment: If it's a function argument, you can remove its name like `void foo(int /*unused_int*/) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the variable, as it is unused. I would argue that in most cases, it is better to resolve this warning by removing (or using) the variable than to suppress it.

Comment: Also, you could use more meaningful variable names, as future practice.